# ssh: one and same proxy jump for multiple (unknown) remotes

Tags: ssh

Is it possible to configure an ssh ProxyJump but still let the user specify the remote server on the command line?

Situation

```
workstation -> jumpserver -> remote1
                          -> remote2
                          -> remote3
                          -> remote4
                          -> remote5
```

With a config similar to this:

```
host jumpserver
     User jump_user
     HostName JJ.JJ.JJJ.JJ
     ForwardX11 yes

host remote
     ForwardX11 yes
     ProxyJump jumpserver
    
host remote1
     User remote_account_A
     HostName remote1
     ForwardX11 yes
     ProxyJump jumpserver
```

I want to be able to run (something like) this on the command line:

```
$ ssh remote remote_account_A@remote55
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way is to use the existing command-line option, `-J`, for ProxyJump:

```
$ ssh -J jumpserver remote55
```

It's about the same amount of typing as in your example.

If all remotes have the same prefix or suffix, define a wildcard `Host` section for all of them:

```
Host remote*
    HostName %h.example.com
    ProxyJump jumpserver
```

You can apply this to all "bare" names using `Host * !*.*`.

If they all resolve under the same domain, use the hostname canonicalization support in recent OpenSSH versions (which performs a two-pass config lookup, once for the short name and again for the expanded domain name). This allows using `ssh remote55` for remotes under one domain, without affecting the same bare-name usage for remotes under another.

```
Host *.example.com
    ProxyJump jumpserver

Host *
    CanonicalizeHostname yes
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ProxyJump` command is used to connect to a bastion host,
but it has a more flexible alternative.

From the RedHat article
[SSH to remote hosts through a proxy or bastion with ProxyJump](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ssh-proxy-bastion-proxyjump):

> **An alternative: Forwarding stdin and stdout**
>
> `ProxyJump` is the simplified way to use a feature that ssh has had
> for a long time: `ProxyCommand`. `ProxyCommand` works by forwarding
> standard in (stdin) and standard out (stdout) from the remote machine
> through the proxy or bastion hosts.
>
> The `ProxyCommand` itself is a specific command used to connect to a
> remote server—in the case of the earlier example, that would be the
> manual ssh command used to first connect to the bastion:
>
> ```
> $ ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p bastion-host" remote-host
> ```
>
> The `%h:%p` arguments to the `-W` flag above specify to forward
> standard in and out to the remote host (`%h`) and the remote host’s
> port (`%p`).

You may find more information in the post
[ProxyCommand use for multiple hops and prompt authentication](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317491/proxycommand-use-for-multiple-hops-and-prompt-authentication),
but I would just quote one command from the
[answer by Jakuje](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/317644/17660):

> p.p.s. for fun here is a oneline but please note this approach is hard
> to type and hard to read:
>
> ```
> ssh -oProxyCommand= \
>   'ssh -W %h:%p -oProxyCommand= \
>     \'ssh -W %h:%p -oProxyCommand= \
>       \\\'ssh -W %h:%p username1@jumphost1\\\' \
>     username2@jumphost2\' \
>   username3@jumphost3' \
> username4@server
> ```
>
> You basically need to go from inside.

There is also given the equivalent config file for the
above command:

> Here is an example `~/.ssh/config` file for your given example:
>
> ```
> Host jumphost1
>     User username1
> Host jumphost2
>     User username2
>     ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p jumphost1
> Host jumphost3
>     User username3
>     ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p jumphost2
> Host server
>     User username4
>     ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p jumphost3
> ```